# How can I de-duplicate records based on a specific column in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of records that is growing, and I'd like to be able to append modified records to it.  However, I'd like to be able to then have a logical view of all of the "newest" versions of each record (highest `modified_date` + unique `primary_key`).  I tried a `JOIN` against the table with a `GROUP BY` `primary_key`, but this then requires that the entire table have `ORDER BY` `modified_date`, which exceeds resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the resource explosion by specifying `PARTITION BY`, which then allows for sorting on a more granular level.  This pattern suffices:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY primary_key ORDER BY modified_date DESC) seq
  FROM
    my_table)
WHERE
  seq = 1;
```

Comment: I don't have a better immediate suggestion aside from this. Rather than deduplicating, another way to think about the problem is that you want the row associated with the max value for a particular group (determined by primary key). The syntax could be something like: MAX(primary_key RETURNING <expr>). I filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=706 if you are interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is now a better way of doing this. Here is an example:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT x, y, MOD(y, 2) AS z
  FROM UNNEST([5, 4, 3, 2]) AS x WITH OFFSET y
)
SELECT
  z,
  ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY y LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS top_x
FROM T
GROUP BY z;
```

This returns the top `x` value as determined by some other column, grouped by a third column. The query in the other answer could be expressed as:

```
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS primary_key, "foo" AS value, DATE('2016-11-09') AS modified_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "bar", DATE('2016-11-10') UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "baz", DATE('2016-01-01')
)
SELECT
  row.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY modified_date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS row
  FROM my_table AS t
  GROUP BY primary_key
);
```

This returns the row associated with the most recent `modified_date`. In theory, you should just be able to use `.*` directly after `[OFFSET(0)]` (and not need a subselect), but there appears to be a bug with column resolution that I'm looking into.